# How to hide page header in Service console

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I want page header and sidebar be visible only if page is loaded in Salesforce Classic. If page is loaded in Service console, I want it to be hidden. How to implement this?

I have button on case layout that executes javascript:

```
window.location.assign('/apex/MyPage');
```

Regular page looke like this:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:outputText value="Hello Salesforce!"></apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

In console it looks this:

[image]

Comment: It should happen automatically without intervention on your part. Can you share an example of it not working?

Comment: @sfdcfox please check edit